# change size of button in DateTimePicker c++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, datetimepicker, tdbgrid

Good Day. Please Help. How change size of buttons (buttons: up, down, open calendar) in component DateTimePicker. I want to do touch application, but buttons too small. And i have the same trouble with ROWS in component DBGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you can do about the button size of the DateTimePicker other than change the height of the client and make the whole thing bigger.  For the DBGrid row you can change this at runtime.

```
dbGrid1->DefaultRowHeight = 50;
```

Or whatever size works for you.

Comment: dbGrid1->DefaultRowHeight; This parametr isn't accessible.

Comment: Weird, works on mine, dbGrid1 is the name of your dbGrid component.

Comment: I understand that its name. compilier said to me that This parametr isn't accessible, as i understand DefaultRowHeight located in private place of class dbGrid and i cannot use it.

Comment: Yaroslav, I am sorry that is for TDBAdvGrid from the TMS components.

Answer (score 0):

There is answear

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class TDBGrid : public Dbgrids::TDBGrid
    {
    public:
        inline __fastcall virtual TDBGrid(Classes::TComponent* AOwner) :
            Dbgrids::TDBGrid(AOwner) {}
        __property DefaultRowHeight; // Now access is public
    };
};
#define TDBGrid MyNamespace::TDBGrid
```